# Android: How to traslate "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather="+cityName xml to get weather in other language?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, weather

I can't traslate the informations about weather in other language.

If I change the URL

```
"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather="+cityName
```

in

```
"http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=it&weather="+cityName
```

to read the information in italian i get the following error:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 537: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

I don't understand why... Tokens and nodes are equal to english ones (try both the urls).

The code that I use is here -> http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=361

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

u need to replace the "&" for "&amp,"

Like this :

```
queryString.replace("&", "&amp,");


, = ;
```